# How to put 3 pages together vertically in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

In InDesign using the "Allow Document Pages to Shuffle" allows for more than 2 pages to be next to each other. I want to do the same, but I want the pages vertically. I am creating a vertical invitation with many panels, and I want each panel to be in a different page. How do I do that?

Thank you,

Virginia

Comment: Can it be done using Adobe Photoshop?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out, so I am sharing...

First turn off "Allow Document Pages to Shuffle", and add as many pages together as you want (they will be aligning horizontally). Then go to the Page Tool and on the panel on top where there are some setting for this tool, click on "Objects Move with Pages" then drag the pages. It behaves like the artboards in Illustrator. You can move the pages apart so there is space between them, or you can move them on top of each other so you get pages aligning vertically.

Comment: Nice find. Must be a CC thing. You should mark your answer correct since it solves the question.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted in CC that the pages you want to stack vertically need to be attached the spread as a whole first (ie - a long line of pages).

Then using the page tool you can attach them to the top or bottom of other existing pages in that overall spread.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating an invitation that folds up, you would probably need each panel to be a slightly different size so when it folds it sits nice and flat.
Personally, I would set a large page size and draw up the layout, make sure it all works and folds as you think, then start placing in your design.
This is the same way I would prepare complex carton or packaging type artwork.
You could easily use inDesign for this (or illustrator), presuming the overall size fits within InDesigns page size limits.

Answer (score 0):

In CC 2015 it seems the "Objects Move with Pages" has been replaced with Page tool > Page Attributes > Rotate Spread View (and then you can choose 90° CW, CCW or 180°).

[image]

Comment: Here you go! https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3546131/Screen%20Shot%202016-06-03%20at%207.00.55%20AM.png